# How to clear the IntelliJ project index?

Tags: macos, intellij-idea

I've run into trouble that makes me suspect there is a bad index file that needs to be cleared. The symptoms are:

- Cmd+N will only find a subset of classes in the project
- Trying to run JUnit test on a package won't find the test classes in that package.

Before suspecting a bad index I reinstalled IntelliJ 8.1.3, then I removed and re-checked out the source code. It didn't help. Only after checking out the code into a different folder did IntelliJ start working correctly again, but only for the new project folder. The old project folder is still *infected*.

So where is that index and how do I clear it?

Comment: File->InvalidateCache

Answer (score 84, accepted):

**File | Invalidate Caches**, restart.
Or manually delete the following folders:

**Linux/Windows**:

- USER_HOME/.IntelliJIdea`XX`/system

**Mac**:

- ~/Library/Caches/IntelliJIDEA`XX`

(where `XX` is your IDEA version).

[See the FAQ](http://devnet.jetbrains.com/docs/DOC-181) for more details and folder locations of the other IntelliJ IDEA platform based products.

Comment: Somehow I read through the File menu twice without finding it, but it's right there near "Synchronize"

Comment: You can always command-shift-A to search for an action. I use that shortcut all the time rather than hunting through menus.

Comment: My ~/Library/Caches/IntelliJIdea13 folder is 13gb and it is not deleted with File-->Invalidate Caches.Should I delete it manually?

Comment: @skiabox it may have caches for the old jars that you no longer use, so it's safe to delete it. Note that you may want to keep the `LocalHistory` subdirectory.

Comment: The big directory inside /Users/Administrator/Library/Caches/IntelliJIdea13 is compile-server.It takes around 11.3Gb.Do you believe that I can delete it?

Comment: @skiabox yes, it's safe to delete it.

Comment: The file option is now called "File | Invalidate Caches/Restart".

Comment: Is there a way to do it only on module basis (maven)?

Comment: No, it's not possible.

Answer (score 6):

For mac you can just hover over the project in recent project list, and click fn + del. that's all.

Answer (score 4):

This happens to me occasionally. Under your home directory (~ on Linux/Unix, C:\Users\LoginName under Vista/Win7, C:\Documents and Settings... under XP) you will find a directory called .IntelijIdea8x. You will want to close down IntelliJ and delete a couple of key directories, most probably:

- system/caches
- possibly system/js_caches;
- possibly system/jsp_caches (although probably not in this case).

Restart it and that should fix it.

Comment: Corresponding path under OS X?

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following now via IDE to invalidate cache:

1. From the main menu, select **File | Invalidate Caches**.
2. In the Invalidate Caches dialog, Click `Invalidate and Restart`.

If you click Just `restart`, cache files etc. won't be deleted.

In case if the above did not solve your problem, proceed with the manual way.

Locate the following Location and hard delete it.

`~/Library/Caches/IntelliJIDEA{version}`