# Why is IntelliJ saying that a class constructor is incorrect despite compiling?

Tags: java, interface, jar, intellij-idea, intellisense

I'm trying to instantiate an object using a class in an external jar. This is a jar that a team-member is developing and recently changed the interface methods.

The problem is that IntelliJ still thinks class constructor should take 4 arguments (the old interface) rather than 3 (new interface).

I can guarantee that the jar in the module dependencies is the new version. This is further confirmed by the fact that the code does successfully compile.

So my question is, why does IntelliJ still think I should have the old interface? Does it have some sort of cache that is not updating properly?

Attached screenshot demonstrates the problem.

Thanks.

[image: Interface Error Screenshot]

Comment: try new IPRing("localhost", 9001, 9001 +"") and tell what happens

Comment: *"The problem is that IntelliJ still thinks class constructor should take 4 arguments (the old interface) rather than 3 (new interface)."* [sic]...  The wording is a bit confusing seen that Java has a very precise definition of the word/keyword "interface" which seem to differ from the way you're using that word : )

Comment: Are you using maven? If yes, there's a "Reimport all maven projects" button.

Comment: @deporter It is the number of arguments that is the problem, not the datatypes. Changing the third argument to a String is still since the constructor requires an int.

Comment: @Vic Maven is being used, but not for that particular jar. That jar just sits in the local lib folder. Will try anyway but I don't think that's the problem.

Comment: @TacticalCoder Yeah, sorry about that. You know what I meant though right? I was just using the word interface fleetingly to mean the expected arguments for the method, as the expected arguments changed from the previous version of the jar. Is 'method signature' the right term?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try move the cursor in the constructor, then press ctrl + b, it will jump to the declaration of constructor, which will get you a chance to double check if the constructor is correct or not.

also you can try "invalidate cache" under "file" menu, this will clear cache and rebuild index for your project.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Right-click on your project and select `Refresh`. Your project is using the compiled jar, which has changed, but your IDE is still using the old compiled jar as it was when it loaded it (even though the new source may be visible in the relevant project).

Eclipse has the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly IntelliJ's indexing info is out of date as it didn't notice that you switched a jar dependency.

This may be resolved at least by restarting the IDE, which then rescans and rebuilds indexes.

Comment: That's what I assumed when it first happened. Tried it bit it didn't help :(

Answer (score 1):

You can also remove all files from folders *caches* and *index* located for example here c:\Documents and Settings\User.IntelliJIdea\system\ (of course you may have another path) and try to start IDE again.

Comment: I'm a mac user and can't find the equivalent directory for this :/

Comment: See http://devnet.jetbrains.net/docs/DOC-181 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/1728354/104891.