# How to make IDEA 12 recognize strings made in IDEA 11 project?

Tags: android, intellij-idea

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to clear the IntelliJ project index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1727922/how-to-clear-the-intellij-project-index)

When I open IDEA 11 Android project in IDEA 12, all strings are colored in red.

[image]

I **can compile** and debugger reports no error, but I **cannot jump to declaration** (Ctrl+B).

This affects **strings only**, and it's not the case with styles (as you can see on the image).

Is this a bug in IDEA 12 or I have to force some kind of refresh? I already tried deleting /gen and /out and /bin directories, but it did not help.

The error which appears is `Cannot resolve symbol`.

Comment: Have you tried to invalidate caches? (File -> Invalidate Caches ...)

Comment: @om-nom-nom Hey, that did the trick. Didn't even know it exists.  Please make a reply so that I can accept it as an answer.

Comment: well, maybe somebody else could post it and explain in details *how exactly and why this work* because for me it's just a magic handle which sometimes helps with this kind of problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to invalidate your caches. To do so, click on **"Invalidate caches"** in File menu (see pic below).

Note that this will invalide caches of all project for the same version on IntelliJ -- so next time you'll open then IDEA will reindex them (but this will take some time).

[image]